# BRE rule not firing when called from ESB Toolkit Itinerary

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2, esb-toolkit-2.0

Running a BizTalk 2013r2 solution, I have the following itinerary:

[image]

All is good up to the selected "Auth Endpoint Detail"

This is calling the BRE, passing the following message:

```
<ns0:MasterCardRequest xmlns:ns0="http://www.EsbToolkit.TargetWebService/Authorization/MasterCardRequest">
  <ns0:AuthAmount>300</ns0:AuthAmount>
  <ns0:CardNumber>1111-1111-1111-1111</ns0:CardNumber>
  <ns0:OrderNumber>130</ns0:OrderNumber>
</ns0:MasterCardRequest>
```

This should cause the following "MasterCard" rule to fire - which would then send endpoint values in the context of the message:

[image]

Problem is - it's not firing! It does fire when I manually "Test Policy" from within the BRE Composer. However, when I run a message through BizTalk and check DebugView, I see the following:

[image]

I have doubled checked that the correct version of the policy is Deployed.
I'd be very grateful for any ideas as to which the rule is not firing.

Comment: How many endpoints are you resolving?  Do you really need to use ESBT?  Roles look like an option here as well.

Comment: Yes, need to use the toolkit for this solution as part of a PoC

Comment: Well, then it's the perfect time to factor ESBT out. :)

Comment: Haha, I take it you're not a fan? I must say, I can find it difficult to justify the additional complexity.

Comment: Winner, winner.  I've never seen ESBT make anything easier, just harder to develop, debug and support.  Dynamic routing is pretty easy to do with just the BRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check if document type property defined in the BRE ruleset matches to DocType shown in the debugview. The BRE resolver mechanics are not well documented, perhaps this will help: [which is the meaning of recognize message format property?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3f120705-c672-4843-8e6d-675ee5d0612e/which-is-the-meaning-of-recognize-message-format-property?forum=biztalkesb)

Also when doctype is meant to be generic, avoiding namespace name in rules is recommended.

Comment: Thanks dmitrio, the problem was my rule stated "Exists in Microsoft.Practices.Esb.ResolveProviderMessage" - the "ESB" letters must be all upper case